# Spring beans: ambiguous constructor when creating a bean

Tags: spring, constructor, javabeans, ambiguous

First, I apologize if this has been answered elsewhere, but I am at a loss as to how to resolve this error.

I have a bean declaration as:

```
<bean id="prefix" class="java.lang.String">
<constructor-arg index="0">
<value>UIO</value>
</constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

From DefaultListableBeanFactory, a message is printed:

> Creating shared singleton instance of instance of singleton bean 'prefix'.

After further messages, `DefaultListableBeanFactory` prints a message:

> Ignoring constructor [public java.lang.String(byte..,int,int,java.nio.charset.CharSet ..
>   Then: Unsatisifed dependency  expressed through constructor argument with index 1 of type[int]: ambiguous constructor.

I searched through the web and saw a similar type of question has been asked and answered a few times,  but I am trying to determine what the definitive answer is.

I also tried the following declarations:

```
<bean id="prefix" class="java.lang.String">
<constructor-arg index="0" type="String">
<value>UIO</value>
</constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="prefix" class="java.lang.String">
<constructor-arg index="0">
<value>"UIO"</value>
</constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

to no avail.

I am sure the answer is relatively simple and I am just missing some syntactic specification, but have been unable to find a definitive syntactic structure that would work consistently.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Guidance as to some documentation would also be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<bean id="prefix" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="UIO"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Predrag: I recieved a message that said it must be terminated by a "</constructor-arg>" tag, which doesn't make sens given the syntax of the statement.

Comment: <bean id="prefix" class="java.lang.String">
<constructor-arg type="java.lang.String">
<value>UIO</value>
</constructor-arg> </bean>

Comment: But, I get a message about Ignoring Constructor with Unsatisfied Dependency ... with index 0 of type [byte[]]. I am not sure if I should also put index="0" in the <constructor-arg statement.

Comment: DId you try with exact code from my answer? It works for me. Also, take a look at [this thread](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/41640-creating-a-java-lang-string-bean) for more working and non working examples.